# Why choose New York for the Prison?

Tags: escape-from-new-york

In Escape from New York, the opening crawl indicates that the crime rate skyrocketed, and that New York City was turned into a supermax prison in the long-distant future (1997). Why, in the name of God, would they choose New York City for that prison, aside from the fact that it's an island? Surely there would be another large uninhabited place that wasn't a major economic powerhouse.

I know that there were some secondary comics and a novelization, I think, so maybe there's an answer out there with a decent level of canonicity.

Comment: My understanding/assumption was that crime had overtaken New York prior to it becoming the "prison". The conversion was a sort of attempt to keep it from spreading outwards as well as a creation of a place to dump additional criminals.

Comment: Definitely no comics (the 2003 "[Chronicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_Plissken#John_Carpenter.27s_Snake_Plissken_Chronicles)" don't deal with NY, and a new comics series just starts in 2014. Good call on novelization though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Out-of-universe**:

  In late 1970s, [NYC was a Bad Place and going downhill](http://www.businessinsider.com/new-york-city-used-to-be-a-terrifying-place-photos-2013-7?op=1). Riots. Power shortages. Major crime. So it's a lot less jarring of a metamorphosis than it seems to you today, with post-Guliani NYC.
- **In-universe from movie:**

  As you yourself said "it's an island". Given that it serves as a prison for **entire** USA (and the crime rate rose 400%, so you need tons of place for all those people - as per novelization, three million), it's hard to find something where you can house sufficient amount of prisoners **and** keep it as secure: (quoting the voice-overs)

  > "The once-great city of New York becomes **the one** maximum-security prison **for the entire country**."...
  >
  > "VOICE A fifty-foot containment wall is erected along the New Jersey shoreline, across the Harlem river, and down along the Brooklyn shoreline.  It completely surrounds Manhattan Island." ...
  >
  > "VOICE **All bridges and waterways** are mined."

  This is reinforced by a futile escape attempt we see at the very beginning of the movie, where a boat with 2 fugitives can't hide and is blown up by the police.
- **In-universe from novelization:**

  Novelization gives more of a back-story for Plissken himself, as well as for New York:

  1. It was basically destroyed by the war (including no sane remaining inhabitants)
  2. It was big enough to house 3 million inmates
  3. As noted in movie-in-univere answer, it was an island with the waterways being a natural security barrier.

  > It had once been called New York City but that, like Hauk’s fortitude, had been before the craziness. Now it was the New York Maximum Security Penitentiary and it held three million killers, cutthroats, thieves and lunatics.
  >
  > ... New York City had been the first North American target in the war. It was under siege for three full weeks with fire bombs and gas. When it was over, those who were left alive were crazy.
  >
  > ... *{{ further describing how the PTSD-ed military vets turned into United States Police Force, and gas-affected poor civilians turned to rampant crime}}*
  > They took to the streets, trained to mayhem, and fought the urban wars with clipped military precision. When they were done, millions lay dead. Those unlucky enough to be left alive were herded onto Manhattan Island. **It was big enough, and uninhabited by anyone sane, and its rivers formed a natural barricade.**

Comment: Having grown up in 1970s New York, DVK's description doesn't even begin to do it justice. I lived in a part of New York lovingly called Hell's Kitchen. Tough town back then. I barely recognize it when I go home now...

Comment: Overwhelming TL;DR - it was destroyed during the war.

Comment: @Thaddeus I'm part of why you don't recognize it. I grew up in suburban NJ in the 70's followed by rural Oregon in the 80's. Now I live in Hell's Kitchen...